# Cannot build any c++ project in vs2012. error LNK1327: rc.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Have tried many ways online but failed finally.Like below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

It said:The rc.exe has stopped;
error LNK1327: rc.exe

Comment: You can try to re-create a new blank project,it seems compiler environment issues

Comment: Frankly, it's not a good question

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with your source code.  Look in the Output window for a better diagnostic from rc.exe.  Otherwise a borken machine kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to reinstall vs? Although it is time consuming, it should be working in most of the cases.